# JQuery Slide in on Div.Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to preface this with the fact that I am very very new to JavaScript and JQuery. I have a moderate amount of CSS and HTML knowledge however.

I have managed to create a set of DIV's which get shown in lots of four, and then hide again on button clicks.
My JavaScript is:

```
function Show() {
    $('div:hidden').slice(0, 4).show();
    $('#hide').show();
}

function Hide() {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('.block:lt(4)').show();
    $('#hide').hide();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ngxyygk/)

However the next thing I want, and herein lies my question, is to make the next four slide(down) in, instead of pop.
I have googled, and overflowed, I even binged! And unfortunately I cant see a way to do this in a way that my beginner JavaScript/Query mind understands enough to modify.

Would appreciate any help, tips, or nudges in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question. There is a jquery animation called slideDown(to show) and one slideUp(to hide). See http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Instead of show() and hide(), simply use slideDown() and slideUp() and your divs will slide. Like this:

```
function Show() {
    $('div:hidden').slice(0, 4).slideDown();
    $('#hide').show();
}

function Hide() {
    $('.block:gt(3)').slideUp();
  $('#hide').slideUp();
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydLgssnf/1/

Comment: Bloody legend! Thanks